# Adding up values of items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, interface, arraylist

ive hit a road block and im stuck with a question on my work.

**Here is the question:**

Provide an implementation of the getLoad method that adds up the individual weights of 
the items in the items list and returns the total.

The items list is:

```
 ArrayList<Item> items;
```

Ive done what i thought was right but for some reason its not working.

Any help on what is wrong, or if what im doing is wrong? thanks

```
@Override
public int getLoad() {
    int load = 0; //declare the variable

    for (Item i : items) { // for each item in the list of items
        load = load + i.getWeight() ; // load equals the weight of the item and adds on
    }
    return load; //returns it
}
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?  Do you have wrong output?  An exception message or compiler error to share?

Comment: We will always want to know what you mean by "not working".

Comment: That looks about right to me. How is it not working? If there's a wrong result, my first guess would be to check if the Item objects are returning correct values for getWeight()

Comment: Define 'not working.'

Comment: When and how `items` array is assigned its values?

Comment: What's the return type of `Item.getWeight()`?

Comment: Okay, its in junit testing and it says Failed: checking Character load expected:<7> but was:<0>

Comment: As it is here, the ArrayList is empty, and thus there are no values to add up. But as others have pointed out, there is probably an issue with the getWeight() method.

Comment: That makes i.getWeight() the likely culprit. Show the Item class to us, please, as well as the item list initialization.

Comment: try running it in debug mode and you should be able to see for yourself what is happening..

Comment: @NPE The return type for getWeight is return weight;

Comment: Is the weight assigned correctly? By the way, csn's suggestion of debugging is an excellent one.

Comment: The getLoad method looks correct if you are looking to find the total of weights from each item. What do you mean by not working? Can you provide more lights on what is "not working"? Most likely it looks like you haven't initialized the items list.

Comment: **Give us minimal code to reproduce the problem**. Handing out tiny pieces of information one at a time in the comments isn't very helpful. If we can't reproduce the issue, we probably can't fix it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The error is saying its not returning the right amount that it should be. Im using it with a pre-made jUnit test and thats the error from it.

Comment: So the item not being initialized doesn't sound an answer?

Comment: Things to try: **(1)** Put `System.out.println(i.getWeight());` at the start of your loop, so you can see what's being added. **(2)** Even better, set a breakpoint and step through this method to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I have initialized it. items = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Cool bob,  can you share the code on what you have added to the items?

Comment: I would but theres an awful lot. Ive got a super class, sub class an interface and another sub class. All are sharing methods and variables between them. Everything else is right, its just that method for getting the weights and totaling them.

Comment: Ok then I would suggest this,  do a System.out of the i.getWeight() and i.getName() or some other unique property to find the problematic item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing I could see going wrong is if `getWeight()` returns a double.  In that case, you should make `int load`: `double load` instead

Comment: Thats a good point but at this point we are only using integers of values like 10, 20 and 15. but thanks for the input

Comment: In that case, your code contains too little information.  If you want more help, please provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you've provided here, I can only take a wild guess that the problem is either:

1. The list `items` is empty even though it shouldn't be. Make sure that Items actually get added to the list! Use a debugger or a printed message to find out if the item list is empty on getLoad().
2. Weights for each `Item` are not assigned correctly, so `getWeight()` returns zero for each of them. Make sure that each `Item` added to the list actually gets assigned its proper weight.

Posting more code would help us give a better answer.